Strain gauge - wheatstone bridge: sensitivity to temperature changes
I have made a strain gauge measurement system using 3-wire quarter-bridge configuration as depicted here:

The bridge is connected to ADC (ADS1262) with ratiometric connection. R1, R2 and R3 sit on the same PCB with ADC and ESP32. I'm happy with its accuracy, but temperature changes on PCB compromise the accuracy.
Maybe I could get rid of self heating of R1, R2, R3 (348R, TC 10ppm/C) by turning on the excitation voltage just momentarily when taking the measurement (one measurement in 10min), and I could put ESP to deep sleep to prevent it heating up the PCB. But I can't control the ambient temperature where the enclosed PCB is placed. I could add temperature measurement on PCB near R1, R2, R3 though.
So my question is this: is it unfeasible to use 3-wire quarter-bridge configuration when the temperature of PCB/enclosure is changing? Can the effects of temperature changes of PCB be mitigated by measuring the temperature of resistors and using some math? Or is a quarter bridge configuration with transverse mounted passive “dummy” gauge to compensate for temperature the only feasible solution (pic below)? I'm worried that the last option will bring some new problems with installation or other.

Just to note that used Kyowa strain gauge itself is "temperature compensated" and in my understanding doesn't need "dummy gauge", spec below.


"Or is a quarter bridge configuration with transverse mounted passive “dummy” gage to compensate for temperature the only feasible solution?"  This is the typical, easiest solution, especially for low-volume situations where temperature compensation is desired.

It also maters the body material temperature coefficient, there are strain gauges with different coeff. to match different body materials coeff.
